# Capture exit code for pytest from python

Tags: python, pytest

When running python.main(), any failed unit tests do not return exit code 1 to python module that invoked the test.

Stated [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code), running pytest will not raise system exit, but is there a way to have failed unit tests behave the same or allow for a return of code (1) to the calling function?

Comment: `exit(pytest.main())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pytest.main()` will return its exit code — which is [an `ExitCode` enum](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html#possible-exit-codes), starting with pytest 5.0.0. If a test has failed, `ExitCode.TESTS_FAILED` will be returned; if all tests pass, `ExitCode.OK` will be returned.

Incidentally, the integer values of these enums are actually the exit codes used if run from the terminal. And here's the source of `site-packages/pytest/__main__.py`, which is executed if `python -m pytest` is used to invoke tests:

```
import pytest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise SystemExit(pytest.main())
```

The `py.test` (or `pytest`) entry point script is largely the same

```
import re
import sys
from pytest import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```